# Realm swift, can't access strongly type name

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Any hint or help why I'm getting `nil` when trying to access property by name, but I'm able to access it by key. Please have a look in example below.

```swift
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = "Rex"
    dynamic var age = 0
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var dog:Dog?
}

let realm = try! Realm()
let people = realm.objects(Person)

print(people.first?.dog?.name) // nil      (Doesn't work)
print(people.first?.dog!["name"]) // Rex   (Works)
```

```js
print(people.first)

Optional(Person {
    name = David Foster Wallace;
    dog = Dog {
        name = Rex;
        age = 0;
    };  
})
```

Please note that this is simulated example, I know that from Realm examples this `Dog,Person` works.

Comment: If, like you said, that example you've provided is already working, then I'm not sure we can help determine what the issue is in your real code. Are you sure you can't post the actual code where the issue is happening?

Comment: Actually I didn't simulate well the example. I guess the problem should be that on `Dog` object in this case I dint declare properties as dynamic!

Comment: Aha! I guess that solved it then! :)

Comment: Yes the problem solved. I was transferring from one system to Realm so I forgot to apply to every model the dynamic keyword. Thanks